# GPS Coordinates Processing

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I want to check a circle intercepts with a line or not. Lets say i have two points with knowing their longitutudes and latitudes. And i also know the circle's longitude, latitude and radius as meter. For example:

- point1 lat1,lon1
- point2 lat2,lon2
- circle lat3,lon3,rad

How can i find the intercept point(s) between the line and the circle? It is easy when they are all in the same unit but i am confused and stucked between coordinates as degrees and radius as meter.

Thanks for your answers from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first try to convert your (latitude,longitude,altitude) to (X , Y , Z) then solve your problem using ordinary approaches.(X,Y,Z) coordinate is named **ECEF Coordinates** .In this coordinate unit of X , Y , Z is meters and form a Cartesian coordinate.

There exists formula for converting (latitude , longitude , altitude) to (X,Y,Z) . In Matlab you can use command `lla2ecef`.You can google for `covert lla to ecef` and you can find plenty of useful fourmula.

If your points is near to each other in earth , you can assume altitude of all is same and is zero for example.So steps are

1. convert (lat1 , lon1 , 0) => (X1,Y1,Z1)
2. convert (lat2 , lon2 , 0) => (X2,Y2,Z2)
3. convert (lat3 , lon3 , 0) => (X3,Y3,Z3)

create a sphere with center `(X3,Y3,Z3)` and radius `rad` and intersect it with line that passes two point `(X1,Y1,Z1) and (X2,Y2,Z2)` then find potentially intersection point(s)

```
(x1 , y1 , z1)
(x2 , y2 , z2)
```

Finally convert them back to LLA (Longitude , Latitude and Altitude) system.In Matlab you can use `ecef2lla` command.